# How to get an EPSON L355 printer working WIFI on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: wireless, printing, epson

USB can print, but not wifi
This printer was working with Ubuntu 12.04 (cable and wifi) on an old PC, but now have a new laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 and can't print wifi.

Downloaded package from http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/main/binary-amd64/epson-inkjet-printer-201207w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb, then installed:
sudo dpkg -i epson*.deb

Thanks

Comment: Is the printer connected to a Wi-Fi router? What to you mean by "can't print wifi"?

Comment: Hello. Yes, I want to print through WiFi router. How can I connect the printer? Thanks

Comment: SOLVED: 1) Download EPSON drivers from [link] (https://www.openprinting.org/driver/epson-201207w/) Choose the right file (.DEB and 32 or 64bits). Epson website gives an error when downloading this specific driver. 2) Install the driver `sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/epson-*.deb` 3) Add the printer (without pluggin the USB cable). Have to wait until Ubuntu find the L355 printer, sometimes not detected at the first time.

Comment: Please post this as an answer, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install epson-inkjet-printer-201207w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb from Epson linux support site

It may need apt --fix-broken install

Then add printer through menus, it will be detected

Another option is to try apt install cups-filters printer-driver-escpr